# R extract a part of a string in R

Tags: string, r, lapply

I have 5 million sequences (probes to be specific) as below. I need to extract the name from each string.

The names here are 1007_s_at:123:381, 10073_s_at:128:385 and so on..

I am using lapply function but it is taking too much time. I have several other similar files. Would you suggest a faster way to do this.

```
 nm = c(
  "probe:HG-Focus:1007_s_at:123:381; Interrogation_Position=3570; Antisense;",
  "probe:HG-Focus:1007_s_at:128:385; Interrogation_Position=3615; Antisense;",
  "probe:HG-Focus:1007_s_at:133:441; Interrogation_Position=3786; Antisense;",
  "probe:HG-Focus:1007_s_at:142:13; Interrogation_Position=3878; Antisense;" ,
  "probe:HG-Focus:1007_s_at:156:191; Interrogation_Position=3443; Antisense;",
  "probe:HTABC:1007_s_at:244:391; Interrogation_Position=3793; Antisense;")

extractProbe <- function(x) sub("probe:", "", strsplit(x, ";", fixed=TRUE)[[1]][1], ignore.case=TRUE)
pr = lapply(nm, extractProbe)
```

Output

```
1007_s_at:123:381
1007_s_at:128:385
1007_s_at:133:441
1007_s_at:142:13
1007_s_at:156:191
1007_s_at:244:391
```

Comment: Dude, just save it into a text file and run grep or something like that. You are using a wrong tool.

Comment: 1) Please make your example reproducible by providing us some code we can easily put into our R sessions, 2) try `mclapply()` on linux/unix or `parlapply` on Windows to run this in parallel. You can probably make your function faster too, but I'm not going through the gymnastics of getting your data into my R session to find out.

Comment: Can you clarify if "HG-Focus:" should be part of the output?

Comment: HG-Focus is not should not appear in the output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using regular expressions:

```
sub("probe:(.*?):(.*?);.*$", "\\2", nm, perl = TRUE)
```

A bit of explanation:

1. `.` means "any character".
2. `.*` means "any number of characters".
3. `.*?` means "any number of characters, but do not be greedy.
4. patterns within parenthesis are captured and assigned to `\\1`, `\\2`, etc.
5. `$` means end of the line (or string).

So here, the pattern matches the whole line, and captures two things via the two `(.*?)`: the `HG-Focus` (or other) thing you don't want as `\\1` and your id as `\\2`. By setting the replacement to `\\2`, we are effectively replacing the whole string with your id.

I now realize it was not necessary to capture the first thing, so this would work just as well:

```
sub("probe:.*?:(.*?);.*$", "\\1", nm, perl = TRUE)
```

Comment: I am sorry for not being so specific. HG-FOCUS may be different string in some other file.

Comment: worked. but would u explain  it a little bit ( specially  "\\2" )

Answer (score 1):

A roundabout technique:

```
sapply(strsplit(sapply(strsplit(nm, "e:"), "[[", 2), ";"), "[[", 1)
```