# Extract part of string

Tags: string, r, extract

I've been trying to extract something from a string (actually a $call) in R, and it's driving me nuts. If you have:

```
library(vars)
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(runif(40)), ncol=2))
z <- matrix(c(runif(40)), ncol=2)
var.modell <- VAR(data, p = 2, exogen=z, type = "trend")
```

How do you extract the z? I've tried googling and searching stack overflow. I found this: [R extract a part of a string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12443278/r-extract-a-part-of-a-string-in-r)

which made me try:

```
sub(".*?exogen=(.*?)", "\\1", var.modell$call, perl = TRUE)
```

But it returns:

```
[1] "VAR"   "data"  "2"     "trend" "z"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the `call` object itself:

```
m <- lm(speed~dist,data=cars)
m$call$data
## cars
```

You'll want `var.modell$call$exogen`.

Comment: Why am I not surprised that the solution was much easier than what I was thinking? Thanks!